# Uso de comillas o comilla simple en laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

Tengo una duda con respecto del uso de comillas en laravel para explicar pongo un fragmento de código.

```
public function index(Request $request){
  $query=trim($reques->('serchText'));
  $categorias=DB::table('categoria')
  ->where('nombre','LIKE','%'.$query.'%')
  ->where('condicion','=','1')
  ->orderBy('idcategoria','DESC')
  ->paginate(7);
  return view('almacen.categoria.index',["categorias"=>$categoria,"serchText"=>$query]);
}
```

en la parte donde retorno la vista uso comilla simple pero si coloco comillas normales igual retorna la vista, no se cual debería usar y por que, por otra parte en la sección donde asigno el valor al parámetro "categorías"

```
["categorias"=>$categoria,"serchText"=>$query]
```

esta bien si lo escribo con esas comillas o debería ser con comida simple, lo que esta entre comillas "categorias" viene a ser un objeto al igual que "serchText"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El uso de las comillas es independiente del framework, es decir que esta es una característica propia del Lenguaje PHP, el uso de las comillas es para especificar un literal tipo String, al declarar Strings en PHP no solo existen esas dos formas para hacerlo, sino que existen 4 formas:

- **Entrecomillado simple**
- **Entrecomillado doble**
- **Sintaxis heredoc**
- **Sintaxis nowdoc (desde PHP 5.3.0)**

## Entrecomillado Simple

Esta es la forma más básica de declarar strings.
Ejemplo:

```
$a = 'Stack Overflow'
$b = 'Car\'s'
```

A diferencia entre las sintaxis de entrecomillado doble y heredoc, las variables y las sentencias de escape para caracteres especiales no se expandirán cuando estén incluidas dentro de un string entre comillas simples. Es decir que `\n` y `$a` seran mostradas como strings literales.

## Entrecomillado Doble

Si un string está delimitado con comillas dobles ("), PHP interpretará las siguientes secuencias de escape como caracteres especiales:

[image: caracteres escapados]

La característica más importante del entrecomillado doble de un string es el hecho de que se expanden los nombres de las variables. Es decir que `"$a"` mostrará el valor a asignado a `$a` y no $a como string literal, ejemplo:

```
$a = 3;
echo "$a"; //Mostrará 3 y no $a
```

En conclusión las comillas simples muestran el texto tal como esta definido, y el uso de comillas dobles interpreta caracteres especiales y además expande el valor de las variables para mostrarlo.

Yendo a tu pregunta, ambas formas están bien, si quisieras tener los indices del arreglo variables por ejemplo podrías usar comillas dobles para definir algo como:

```
["categorias_$id"=>$categoria] //Si por ejemplo $id = 1 obtendrías categorias_1
```

Aunque lo anterior también se podria hacer con comillas simples de la siguiente manera:

```
['categorias_'.$id =>$categoria]
```

Sin embargo esto podría hacer un poco ilegible el código en caso de que concatenes más valores.

Para más información de las otras formas de definir strings revisa la documentación oficial de PHP http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php

La siguiente pregunta de SO inglés tambien te puede ser útil https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php